# Web service para web/android

Tags: android, web-service, aplicação-web, slim, slimframework

Eu tenho o seguinte web service

```
$app->get('/alunos', function(){
require_once('db/config.php');
foreach ($db->alunos()
             ->order("nome")
         as $row){
    $data[]=$row;
}

echo  json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //para android

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views/alunos/');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array());

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('registar.php');
echo $template->render(array('data' => $data)); //para web
});
```

Alguém sabe como eu posso mostrar o webservice correto para android/web e não os dois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que passar um parâmetro durante a requisição, informando qual webservice você deseja acessar. Seria uma alternativa meia boca, melhor mesmo seria ter um webservice para cada dispositivo, pois permite que você personalize eles de forma independente.

Ou, ainda mais meia boca, verificar se quem ta acessando é um dispositivo mobile e tratar isso, uma ferramenta que pode fazer isso é o http://mobiledetect.net/